# Trying to remove linebreaks from text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a text file which i wish to convert into an excel worksheet so that it is easier for viewing. The entire text is separated into paragraphs where the sentences contain line breaks and each paragraphs end with a full stop and 2 line breaks before the new paragraph starts as follows:

This is the first item and it contains several info
that may contain line breaks in the middle of the paragraph
it may contain a list of items: 1)apple; pear;
oranges. It will contain fullstops or any punctuations in between,
how do i separate them into excel.

This is a new paragraph that contains another set of info with
different punctuations. It can contain semicolons; commas, full stops.
and have line breaks in between paragraphs but a new paragraph always
start after a full stop and 2 line breaks. So there is always an empty
line in between 2 paragraphs.

So how do I make excel recognize that I want one paragraph in one cell or how do i remove the line breaks in between each paragraphs?

I tried doing the usual method of replacing empty spaces with nothing in notepad but notepad doesnt recognize "\n" or "\t" to replace. I have tried pandas read_csv function to read it as a dataframe using seperators but pandas still recognises one line break as one row when i am trying to put the whole paragraph as one row in the data frame. Please help!

Edit(adding more details):
this is a sample of the file i am trying to convert from txt:

Nicholas Koh ( a.k.a Nkoh; a.k.a Nick; a.k.a. Nic),
Australia, Student: Majoring in Computer Science,
Burgandy Street 1, Postal Code 123456 [placeholder].

Tim Jordan ( a.k.a Tim; a.k.a Jordan; a.k.a TJ),
United States, Doctor: Specializing in Oncology,
Whisky Street 11, 1232123 [Placeholder].

i tried running read_csv() directly on the txt file with the sep argument but it is still reading every line break as one entry even when i tried defining the sep as sep=".\t" as each paragraph ends with a full stop and a blank line

Comment: Could you try adding a sample of your file?  And maybe some of the code you've tried to use to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use this code for parcing using replace methods

```
df1=df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(";",'') if isinstance(x, str) else x) # map function for replacing punctuations
df1=df1.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(",",'') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: this method works to remove the characters specified but i am trying to remove all the line breaks between each sentence in the paragraph too. Else pandas would take each line as a individual row!

Comment: Then you can use separator sep="\s+" instead of "\t"